# Cannot access to S3 bucket after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, aws

I'm using the following line in `/etc/fstab` to mount an Amazon Web Services S3 bucket on boot.

```
s3fs#codesurfer-fs:/s3-drive /shares/private-synced fuse _netdev,allow_other,passwd_file=/home/mkay/.passwd-s3fs,use_cache=/tmp/s3-cache,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022 0 0
```

Everything worked till the other day, when I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04.

Now the S3 bucket doesn't mount at boot, but once the system booted, if I launch the command `sudo mount -a` the bucket is mounting correctly.

Any advice?

Comment: I wonder if /home is a different partition than root and mounted later?  Since you are mounting /shares globally shouldn't the passwd file located globally like in /etc?

Comment: @AndrewGaul /home is the same partition than /root. I’ve tried with the passwd file in many locations, but all of those failed. I’ve resolved: the OS is on a VMWare ESXi virtual machine; the issue was on the difference between the host and the guest timedate.

Comment: Can you share a bit more about how this failed?  Was it a mismatch between the S3 server time and the guest time which caused requests to fail?  Could this have been logged more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Working well for me on Ubuntu 20.04
/etc/fstab

```
s3fs#my-bucket /home/ubuntu/s3disk fuse allow_other,nonempty,use_path_request_style,iam_role=auto,url=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com,endpoint=us-west-2 0 0
```